# Delayed effect on showing new rows in table

Tags: jquery, delay, rows

I've made a jsfiddle to make it simpler for me to explain. (http://jsfiddle.net/FPznm/).
What I'm trying to do is that when you click the 'Visa mer' button at the end of the table I want the hidden rows to be faded in with a delay.

It does not work as it currently is and I don't know why. (See the Javascript window on jsfiddle).

The problem is that if I add an `.delay()` before `.fadeIn()` the `fadeIn()` effect disappears but they still gets displayed.

```
  for (i = 0; i <= increaseBy; i++) {
        hidden.eq(i).delay(i * 20).fadeIn(500);
        hidden.eq(i).removeClass("hidden");
    }
```

This is the code where the trouble is at. I'm figuring that `.eq()` is what's making it not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the animation is asynchronous, so you are removing the class instantly

Try this instead..beware that table rows do not animate well

```
$("td.showMore").on('click', function() {
        var hidden = $("tr.hidden"),
            increaseBy = 5;
        for (i = 0; i <= increaseBy; i++) {
            hidden.eq(i).delay(i * 200).fadeIn(1000, function(){ 
                   $(this).removeClass("hidden");
            });

        }
    });
```

EDIT: Also note that your delay of `20` is 20ms which 1/50th of a second, the human eye can't even register that

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/FPznm/7/ Thanks!
The delay of 20ms is multiplied by 0-4 as you loop it. So at the the end the delay is at 80ms. These are very short delays but I definitely get the result I wanted.

Comment: Hmm. I get an error I've never seen before when I try to implement the new script. (see image http://i.imgur.com/DiHRp.png).

Comment: syntax eror somewhere. Use Firebug will show you which line. Works fine here  http://jsfiddle.net/FPznm/8/

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/CtB2r.png I have no idea what's wrong.
**edit:** I fixed it by deleting it and retyping it.

Answer (score 1):

That's because `removeClass` is executed faster than `fadeIn` method, you can remove the class when animation is complete.

```
hidden.eq(i).delay(i * 20).fadeIn(500, function(){
    hidden.eq(i).removeClass("hidden");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/k28WT/

If you want to select the first 5 elements with class of `hidden` you can  use `:lt` selector:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("td.showMore").on('click', function() {
        $("tr.hidden:lt(5)").each(function(i){
            $(this).delay(i + 200).fadeIn(500, function(){
               $(this).removeClass('hidden')
            })
        })
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vex3R/

Comment: This works. However, it doesn't remove the "hidden" class for some reason. (see http://jsfiddle.net/FPznm/4/)

Comment: @WillB Are you sure, I can see in the fiddle that the class is removed. check this http://jsfiddle.net/vex3R/

Answer (score 1):

I have created a fiddle which explains my answer: http://jsfiddle.net/3leven11/FPznm/5/

All you need to do is this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("td.showMore").on('click', function() {
        var increaseBy = 5;
        $("tr.hidden").each(function(index, elem) {
            if (index <= increaseBy) {
                $(elem).delay(index * 20).fadeIn(500, function() {$(elem).removeClass('hidden');});
            }
        });
    });
});​
```

Comment: I did this at first. But with the $.each() function I had trouble with restraining it to only show the next 5 hidden elements.

Comment: Updated my answer to respect the increaseBy value.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove this line: `hidden.eq(i).removeClass("hidden");`

`fadeIn` is asynchronous: internally it's probably working with `setTimeout` or `setInterval`. You've specified to have the fadeIn completed after 500 ms, but are removing the `hidden` class immediately after (without waiting for the 500 ms to pass)

If you need to change a class or do something else after the `fadeIn` is done, you can provide a call back to `fadeIn`, that will be executed after the animation is done. For more details see: http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/

Comment: if the class isn't removed will need to modify the logic to slice new elements to show

Comment: as I said, you can simply remove the class in the callback for fadeIn